# Change php var with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, select

I want to change the php var on the selected option like :

```
<select id="price-leval" name="price_leval" >
                    <option value="1" id="asdasd">1</option>
                    <option value="2" id="asdasd">2</option>
                    <option value="3" id="asdasd">3</option>                    
                </select>
```

I have this vars:

```
$price1 = $price['price_1'];
$price2 = $price['price_2'];
$price3 = $price['price_3'];
```

And this code too:

```
$html.= '<input type="text"  name="cat_val['.$item->id.']" data-cat="'.$item->id.'" class="type-cat type-'.$item->id.'" >';
```

So, I want to add a rel like this:

```
$html.= '<input type="text"  rel="'.$price1. or $price2 or $price3'" name="cat_val['.$item->id.']" data-cat="'.$item->id.'" class="type-cat type-'.$item->id.'" >';
```

so, I want to change the rel value if the select option is value =1 to show $price1 if it's value = 2 use $price 2 and so on.

Comment: IDs should always be unique within the same page.

Comment: javascript happens on the client, php on the server. You can modify the page with javascript after it has loaded but you can't touch the php- it has already finished executing by the time javascript starts up.

Comment: So there's no way to change the var on selection?

Comment: You are facing an XY problem. [edit] your question and explain what and why you are trying to do instead of what the code should do.

Comment: so, I want to change the rel value if the select option is value =1 to show $price1 if it's value = 2 use $price 2 and so on.

Comment: The browser is the display value; changing that will only change what is shown. Refresh the page and you'll see it set to the original value. The server holds the data (unless this is a single-page app, in which case it is mostly javascript...) and changing that won't be reflected to the user. You need to change both; this is done with form submissions, or AJAX calls to the server and changing the display value on a success...

Answer (score 1):

You can't change a PHP variable. But you can manipulate the DOM. The "easiest" way would be to add a `<script>` tag:

```
<head>
    <!-- foo -->
    <script>
        $( '#your-id' )
            .attr( 'rel', '<?php echo join( " ", $_POST['prices'] );?>' );
    </script>
```

This way you simply fetch your data from the `$_POST` values and add them as attribute. Make sure that you properly sanitize and validate your data. `filter_var()` and friends...